# Mongoose timestamps aren't set or updated when using $set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mongoose timestamps in my schema:

`{ timestamps: true }`

but then when I use `$set` on my document like so:

```
$set: {
  "person.name": "Owen",
},
```

The timestamps (`createdAt` & `updatedAt`) aren't set or updated.

but when I use `$set` like so:

```
$set: {
    person: {
        name: "Owen"
    }
}
```

then it does work.

Is this the expected behaviour? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: did you confirm that the first query actually modifies the document?

Comment: check the docs, it says how it works and when.. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/timestamps.html

perhaps it will give you a clue, also, I would suggest turning the debugger on if you haven't.